# set Argument for fragment in xml layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

i used this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="sanjaqak.com.karaoke.artist.AllArtistActivity">


    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="sanjaqak.com.karaoke.Srch.SrchSubFrag"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this fragment must have argument to work. but i don't know how can initialize argument for this.
i am very sorry for bad speak English.

Comment: i think it is not possible to add arguments from xml to fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible with the current Fragment framework.

In such cases I just create the parent ViewGroup (usually a simple [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)) for the Fragment that needs correct runtime arguments to work, and load that Fragment with those Arguments in the Activity's / parent Fragment's setup phase (usually in `.onCreate()`) into that ViewGroup.